# Google Play Billing integration in Android project with Java - Room Database for Product IDs and Subscription Management

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm working on an Android project written in Java, and I'm trying to integrate Google Play Billing. I want to achieve the following features:

1. Load product IDs from a Room database: On the splash screen, I want to download the product IDs and store them in a Room database. How can I accomplish this?
2. Implement four subscription types: I need to offer four subscription options to users:

   - Monthly subscription
   - Quarterly subscription
   - Yearly subscription
   - One-time purchase (non-consumable)
3. Enable changing subscriptions: After a purchase, I want to give the user the option to change their subscription. If the user clicks on this button, I should show them the subscription list again.

   However, if the user clicks on an item they have already purchased, I should display a message indicating that the item has already been purchased. If the user tries to buy a subscription they haven't purchased before, it should be bought and start after the current plan ends. How can I implement this behavior?

I have attempted to implement these features, but I'm encountering errors. Could you please provide guidance and code examples on how to accomplish these tasks correctly? Thank you.

I have been attempting to integrate Google Play Billing into my Android project using a specific library. However, I am encountering a problem where the isAcknowledged property always returns false, even after I perform the acknowledgment process correctly.

Additionally, I am unsure about how to utilize this library to implement a subscription change feature. Could you please provide guidance on both resolving the isAcknowledged issue and implementing the subscription change functionality? Any code examples or explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `I have attempted to implement these features, but I'm encountering errors`, show us what you attempted & what are the exact errors, stacktrace if there were crashes.